# The use of "で" and "を” in this sentence

Tags: grammar, particle-で, particle-を

こうえんをさんぽします。

Why in this sentence do we use を　and not で。

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making sense of transitive usage of 行く and 来る - 「を行く」 and 「を来る」](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-and-%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b-%e3%80%8c%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f%e3%80%8d-and-%e3%80%8c%e3%82%92%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b%e3%80%8d)

Comment: @Ash That explains this use of を, but it doesn't really comment on whether で is acceptable.  I think this is a new question and that an answer should discuss `こうえんでさんぽします。`.

Comment: I asked a native speaker the same question when the following came up: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/15221/explain-how- I was told it was grammatically possible but not done. In does not sound natural. (Perhaps this could loosely  be explained in Japanese as: You take walk around the park, not in/at it.)

Comment: The way i look at this sentence is the same as 
こうえんであそびます。
I thought I understood the use of を で に but then came this sentence it made me confused.
I checked the link Ash　and tim posted and how i can look at it as going through and leaving something behind however walking in the park doesn't mean am going through it (going from 1 gate and exiting from the other) i can look at it as doing an action in the park thats why am confused and i thought it would take で。

Comment: Both こうえんをさんぽ and こうえんでさんぽ are fine but 空で飛ぶ is nonsensical (because the sky is an only place to fly).

Answer (score 1):

**For the case of 散歩, both are grammatical but with a slightly different meaning.**

https://youtu.be/5zpAze8KPtw?t=368

- use を for "going across" (in and out) of something
- use で for "moving/circling inside" of something

As mentioned in the video, while 通ります cannot use で since it only carries the "across" meaning, 散歩 can use either because in the 'exercise' context it can have the meaning of "circling inside the park".