# when を means at

Tags: particles

I've seen phrases like 私は空**を**飛んでいますwhich mean "I'm flying in the sky" but typically I see this represented as で like 私はプール**で**泳いでいます meaning "I am swimming in the pool".

I try googling it but I  don't still don't understand. So It will be better if you could provide some examples.

Comment: It doesn't mean 'at'. It is more like 'through'. See this question for example: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/3243/making-sense-of-transitive-usage-of-%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-and-%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b-%e3%82%92%e8%a1%8c%e3%81%8f-and-%e3%82%92%e6%9d%a5%e3%82%8b

Comment: Related/duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3255/9831 / https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15221/9831